# Monitoring the check state of a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, monitoring

What is the best way to automatically check if a checkbox has been (un)checked. I know that the onclick event will catch click events but what if another script changes the state of the checkbox ala "check all button".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the change event to monitor for programmatic changes (changes, not originated from a click) to the checkbox. So you'll have to make up your own monitor. One way is to use `setInterval` for periodic checking. Something like: `setInterval(checkstate,2000);`. See this [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/w7U8j/) to see an example in action.

Comment: I figured this option was going to show up. I have used onchange but it seems unpredictable across browers. I was just trying to avoid using cpu cycles to pool a checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the 'change' event. The behavior is buggy in IE, so you might have to observe both click and change - http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html.

Comment: It isn't "buggy" in IE, it is implemented per the W3C HTML 4.01 specification, which says it should fire when the control loses focus if it has been modified. Unfortunately that behaviour is confusing, so most use the click event instead and use the element's checked property.

Comment: The `change` event won't detect a programmatic change using something like `[checkbox].checked = true/false`

Comment: I agree with you. if it acted the same in all browsers and detected programmatic changes, I would've used the onchange event.

Answer (score 1):

using the `checked` property and the `CheckboxStateChange` event. I don't know about compatibility, though.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/checkbox

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Events

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/radiocheck.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You can define one **global** variable in java script and change its state to checked
or unchecked on click that changes the state of check box and on another script changes
the state of the check box

Answer (score 0):

The other scripts should initiate a checkbox click in code itself. The event will bubble even if initiated from script. Here is an example if you are interested --> http://jsfiddle.net/qSRzM/1/